# No menu for adding WSL python interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-ide

I was following [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#configure-wsl) from official jetbrains page, until the step 2 comes in the existence.

In the picture mentioned in that page, has so many options like ssh, wsl, vagrant, docker, etc. In my pycharm (latest 2019.3.4) it only shows 4 options - venv, conda, pipenv and system-interpreter.

> There is no WSL menu in the add python interpreter dialog.

See the below image:

[image]

Searched web for an hour and found no results that show how to fix it. I started plugin search in the PyCharm if there's an external plugin to do so, but there were no plugin named as WSL.

I don't know how to setup the WSL interpreter, I have python3.8 installed on my wsl right now.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I was going to ask the very same question actually. I'm having the same problem. Prerequisite is to use professional edition, be on windows, wsl installed. All good on these ones. However, there is one thing catches my eye, when I go to plugins and search for wsl, there is "WSL plugin" looks disabled. I enable it, restart pycharm but it doesn't take effect. Clean reinstall didn't solve :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have solved this by

- Uninstalling pycharm with history and cache.
- Removing folders completely from `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local` and `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains` and
- Clean re-install of pycharm
- WSL interpreter option shows up as normal
- Ideavim is creating a conflict I guess.

Comment: Which folder did you move from C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local? JetBrains forled only?

Comment: @user48115 unfortunately WSL interpreter support is only available in professional edition of PyCharm.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, Thank you. That was an important notice. 
I've just reinstall again PyCharm, this time the professional version.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu is there a way to configure it for community edition?

Comment: @mp252 unfortunately not, I ended up using VSCode, it has a good support for it, and when integrated with Material theme + Python extension + Code runner, it basically work like a fully-fledged IDE.

Comment: I didn;t have to reinstall, just deleting the `appdata` folders was enough

Comment: Worked for me. It finally worked after I deleted `C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains`.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me without having to reinstall PyCharm. In PyCharm go to

- File, Manage IDE Settings, **Restore Default Settings**.

I think PyCharm was unable to find my WSL after I updated my WSL's Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 and changed the name. (Maybe this issue wouldn't have come up if I had kept the name "Ubuntu-20.04".)